# SSH hangs for several minutes at a time

Tags: networking, centos, ssh

I can SSH into a server and run commands just fine, but usually within a minute or so the session will appear to hang (become unresponsive). I can type commands but they're not even echoed on  the terminal. But they *are* queuing up and will eventually run. This began on *most* of our servers after a minor network change was made, but the network team has been unable to determine a cause and is pointing to a systems problem. I'm at my wits end and am about to just start reinstalling OSes to see if that helps. I've run `tcpdump`s on both the server and client side and all I see are large gaps in time and a few TCP resets here and there, but nothing definitive. Sysstat isn't showing any I/O issues or anything either.

I'm running CentOS 6 with `openssh-server-5.3p1-104`.

Comment: If you suspect SSH then to troubleshoot this you can enable telnet and run two sessions side by side and compare.  I would guess both of them will freeze at the same time pointing to a networking issue instead.

Comment: a continuous ping should show the same. Could be something like a dodgy default gateway and ICMP redirects.

Comment: Could be due to a router not handling the ToS field set by openssh and delaying/dropping packets.

Answer (score 3):

Connections which stall and eventually recover is almost certainly caused by packet drops. It should be very clear from a packet capture, when there has been a packet drop. If a packet was send by one end of the connection and not received by the other end, then it must have been dropped by the intermediate network.

It is possible that packets are corrupted in-flight rather than being dropped. In that case you should be looking for data packets, which do not trigger an ACK. If you can find any of those, then check if the packet on the receiving end differs from what was send.

This sort of analysis is easiest performed by dumping the traffic to a file while reproducing the problem, and then downloading both pcap files to the machine where you will inspect the files. I can recommend Wireshark for looking at details of the packets.